# GatsbyJS export styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, export, gatsby, styled-components

I have created a elementStyles.js file where I am storing some styled-components to later use within my GatsbyJS site: `import { Wrapper, PageContent } from "../components/StyledElements/elementStyles"`

However, for some reason it keeps giving me error:

```
"Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."
```

My styled components .js file:

```
import styled from "styled-components"

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1920px;
  padding: 0;
`

export const PageContent = styled.div`
  background-color: #455260;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 90px;
  color: #eff1ef;
  font-weight: 300;
`
```

If I remove PageContent and write export default Wrapper at the end it works without problems.

Therefore I've tried to export with different methods:

```
export default { Wrapper, PageContent }
```

Any clues on what I might be missing?

Comment: Looks a lot like you're exporting an object. You sure you haven't combined the two approaches?

Comment: yup... My file is a described in the post. I've deleted the export default again.

Comment: Got a new error: "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."